# Can you download a file sending post data using Filetransfer? (phonegap)

Tags: cordova, http-post, download, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

What if I need to send post data to the url before downloading a file?
For example I need to send some key and the file id as post data to the url before downloading the file.

This is how the code goes:

```
var downloadUrl = "http://mysite/test.pdf";
var relativeFilePath = "MyDir/test.pdf";  // using an absolute path also does not work

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
   var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
   fileTransfer.download(
      downloadUrl,

      // The correct path!
      fileSystem.root.toURL() + '/' + relativeFilePath,

      function (entry) {
         console.log("Success");
      },
      function (error) {
         console.log("Error during download. Code = " + error.code);
      }
   );
});
```

But where do I send the post data? is it even possible? There is a options field but "currently only supports headers (such as Authorization (Basic Authentication), etc)."

Comment: You could do an ajax post method and if it returns successful, then trigger the file download, else do not trigger the download.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that solves the problem.

Comment: are you able to use GET instead of POST?

Comment: No, POST is a must. Anyways I ended up using filewriter after all and got it working just some minutes ago. I'll post the answer in a while. Thanks for the idea though.